# Reaching upon $9=1$ while solving $x$ for $3\tan{(x-15^{\circ})}=\tan{(x+15^{\circ})}$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

> $x$ for $3\tan{(x-15^{\circ})}=\tan{(x+15^{\circ})}$

Substituting $y=x+45^{\circ}$, we get
  $$3\tan{(y-60^{\circ})}=\tan{(y-30^{\circ})}$$
$$3\frac{\tan y - \sqrt3}{1+\sqrt3\tan y}=\frac{\tan y - 1/\sqrt3}{1+1/\sqrt3\cdot\tan y}$$

$$3(\tan ^2 y-3)=3\tan ^2-1$$

$$9=1$$

The solution provided by the book $x=n\pi  + \pi/4$ fits, so why did i get $9=1$?

Comment: How did you get to the third line ($3(\tan^2 y-3) \cdots$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got $$0\cdot\tan^2{y}+9=1.$$ Id est, you got that $\tan{y}$ does not exist.

Thus, $$y=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n,$$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z},$ or
$$x+45^{\circ}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n,$$ which gives $$x=\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
We did not get a contradiction in Math!

Comment: If $9=1$, then how sure are u that it is $\tan y$ that does not exist? It could be $\tan (x-15)$ or the other trigonometric ratios...

Comment: @rash We got $0\cdot\tan^2y+9=1.$

Comment: @rash: Another way to look at it ... From the step $3 \tan^2y-9 = 3 \tan^2y - 1$, we see that subtracting either $9$ or $1$ from $3\tan^2y$ gives the same result. We can (somewhat informally) conclude that $3\tan^2y$ —and, more specifically, $\tan y$— must be *infinite*.

Comment: One solution of X-9=X-1is X is undefined or X tends to infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Set $\tan y=\dfrac1a$

$$\dfrac{3(1-\sqrt3a)}{a+\sqrt3}=\dfrac{\sqrt3-a}{\sqrt3a+1}$$

$$\iff3-a^2=3(1-3a^2)\iff a=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way to avoid confusion:

$$\dfrac31=\dfrac{\sin(x+15^\circ)\cos(x-15^\circ)}{\cos(x+15^\circ)\sin(x-15^\circ)}$$

Apply [Componendo et Dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm)

$$\dfrac{3+1}{3-1}=\dfrac{\sin2x}{\sin30^\circ}$$

Comment: I've never heard of *Componendo et Dividendo*! $(+1)$